# BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles deprecated (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a scene in Unity that will feature augmented reality. I would like my 3D object to be loaded from an external server. I was following a youtube tutorial on how to do that and he uses this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

public class CreateAssetBundles : MonoBehaviour
{
 [MenuItem("Assets/Build AssetBundles")]
 static void BuildAllAssetBundles()
 {
     BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles("Assets/AssetBundles");
 }
}
```

However, `BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles` is said to be deprecated. There are added parameters which I have no idea what to put. This is my first time using Build Pipeline. How do I fix this? I tried asking in unityanswers but sadly noone was able to help me so I'm hoping that someone can help me here.

Comment: google -> BuildAssetBundles -> Lucky shot -> [result](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles.html)

Comment: Can't believe I missed this. Thank you very much!